# XSL:FO How to get the img src from xml and then use it as src for fo:external-graphic

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

Question: How to get the `src` attribute from the `img` element, then copy the `src`'s value it into a **variable**, and then set the **variable** as the `src` for the `fo:external-graphic` element?

Assume that I have a XML document with an image that looks like this:

```
<diffreport>
<css />
<diff>
    <p>
        <span class="diff-html-removed" id="removed-diff-0" previous="first-diff"
            changeId="removed-diff-0" next="added-diff-0">
            <img alt="" id="Rxed6OQAKXfCYA"
                src="D:\udu\img1.jpg" changeType="diff-removed-image" />
        </span>         
    </p>
</diff>
```

**Note: Assume the `src` paths for every `img` element will be dynamic.**

I confirmed that this piece of code bellow works ok, but it is not good because it is hard coded. I would really like to know how to replace the ***"url('D:\udu\img1.jpg')"*** with a **variable** so that the code is dynamic.

```
<!-- Image -->
<xsl:template match="img">
    <fo:external-graphic
        src="url('D:\udu\img1.jpg')"></fo:external-graphic>
</xsl:template>
```

Is there any way to doing this? Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
<xsl:template match="img">
    <fo:external-graphic
        src="{concat('file:///', translate(@src, '\', '/'))}" />
</xsl:template>
```

which will get `D:\udu\img1.jpg` and have it called as `file:///D:/udu/img1.jpg`

Comment: Needs `{` and `}` around the `concat(...)` for it to be evaluated as an expression.

Answer (score 0):

Use an **attribute value template** that will be evaluated to get the value of the `@src` from your XML.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates

```
<!-- Image -->
<xsl:template match="img">
  <fo:external-graphic src="url('{@src}')" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: is there any way to put source from xml without defining a variable

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your comment.